# How do I correctly group albums in Banshee?

Tags: 10.10, music, banshee, android

I use Banshee to manage & play my music (most of which came from emusic and CDs). I consistently have problems getting songs from the same album to appear as one album. This is particularly a problem with compilations, i.e. multiple artists on the same album. When I transfer songs to my Android phone (Nexus S), this issue follows. How do I edit files so that Banshee correctly identifies all the songs as belonging to the same album?

I am using the latest Banshee via the unstable PPA.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to select the songs you want to change using Shift-click and go to the following dialog box (from right clicking on your selection and choosing "Edit Track Information"):

[image]

Then make sure the "Compilation Album Artist" is checked, and put what you want in the input box.  Click on the button next to the input box, then click "Save".  Your album should all show up under one cover now.